# Dummy Variable Excluded from Regression Output in R? (Panel data w/ fixed effects)

Tags: r, fixed, effects, plm

I am running a regression for an economics paper using panel data, but one of my dummy variables does not show up in the output (i.e. doesn't seem to be included in the model) with a fixed effects model. Is there any reason why this would be? If I run a regression with fewer variables (or untransformed variables) the problem still occurs.

This is the relevant code:

```
library(car)
library(plm)

euro$rsign<-sign(euro$r)
euro$rsign2<-ifelse(euro$rsign==0, 1, euro$rsign)
euro$rlogmod<-euro$rsign2*log(abs(euro$r)+1.3)
hist(euro$rlogmod)
euro$logvix<-log(euro$vix)
hist(euro$logvix)
euro$logtdo<-log(euro$tdo)
hist(euro$logtdo)

eurofix<-plm(rlogmod~db+gdp+logvix+gb+i+logtdo+fx+ld+e+c,data=euro,model="within")
summary(eurofix)
```

The coefficients never seem to include "c" while they do include "ld" and "e", which are also dummy variables.

Here is the output for summary(eurofix):

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = rlogmod ~ db + gdp + logvix + gb + i + logtdo + 
    fx + ld + e + c, data = euro, model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n=21, T=44, N=924

Residuals :
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-1.2200 -0.2910 -0.0283  0.2860  1.8000 

Coefficients :
          Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
db      0.01308207  0.00223606  5.8505 6.872e-09 ***
gdp     0.00171493  0.00225507  0.7605 0.4471692    
logvix  1.19584210  0.04590883 26.0482 < 2.2e-16 ***
gb      0.14940903  0.02253779  6.6293 5.828e-11 ***
i       0.06406398  0.01737038  3.6881 0.0002396 ***
logtdo  0.05584335  0.02871523  1.9447 0.0521208 .  
fx      0.09831212  0.10642503  0.9238 0.3558560    
ld     -0.10248830  0.05161567 -1.9856 0.0473824 *  
e       0.00085249  0.07662002  0.0111 0.9911252    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    408.3
Residual Sum of Squares: 173.97
R-Squared      :  0.57393 
      Adj. R-Squared :  0.55529 
F-statistic: 133.804 on 9 and 894 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

"ld" is simply if a certain time period is before or after the Lehman default, "e" is if a country is in the eurozone or not, and "c" is if a country is considered part of the eurozone "core". If I run this model with random effects, the "c" variable is included.

Disregarding the obvious significance errors, where am I going wrong? I can't work on refining my model right now if "c" is not there.

Edit: plm is from the plm package. Here is a link to the dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IMIFdAm4l3be88PU_WAaTxzs1N8weqyDH9F6yULvBn0/edit?usp=sharing Also sample screenshot of my r dataset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2uYc.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide your code and data so that we may have a reproducible example of your problem and can better assist you. This is very likely a purely statistical problem that you're having, however it could be code related. It's impossible to tell without seeing your code and data.

Comment: Agreed. It's not even clear what package the function `plm` is from. Do you mean `plm::plm`?

Comment: your sample dataset is small, but I'm wondering if c is a linear combination of other predictors, namely `e` and `id`.  I think `model.matrix` (which plm relies on) will drop predictors that are a linear combination of other predictors.  A call to `lm(rlogmod ~ db + gdp + logvix + gb + i + logtdo + 
    fx + ld + e + c, data = euro)` will confirm that this isn't specific to `plm()`

Comment: I also considered the possibility that `c` was being dropped because it was linearly dependent with other factors, but when I tabled it with the other 0/1 variables I didn't see definite evidence of that fact. Furthermore, when I do run a `lm` model, I do see an estimate for `c`. To BenHuang, you should definitely stop using the letter "c" as a variable name. You will get very confusing error messages when you make errors involving the very central R function name.

Comment: Hi Jthorpe, "c" should not be a linear combination of any other variables. If I use a standard lm model or random effects instead of fixed, "c" shows up. The only time it doesn't is with the fixed effects. But I will change the names as BondedDust mentioned in case of future confusion.

Comment: Did you solve this? It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.